# Docker compose version unsupported

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I was using `version: '3'` for the docker-compose, works fine in my host machine (macOS), but when I tried to build the images and run the containers in the server, I got the response

```
Version in "./docker-compose.dev.yml" is unsupported. You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a version of "2" (or "2.0") and place your service definitions under the services key, or omit the version key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/
```

```
OS Ubuntu "16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)" in AWS (ec2)
Docker version 19.03.8
docker-compose version 1.8.0, build unknown
```

I found a way around and it is to use **version 2**, How can I solve this?

Comment: upgrade docker-compose may be ?
https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/